# Disable animation on notifyItemRangeInserted()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm using a RecyclerView. After adding items to the RecyclerView, I need to call:

```
notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount);
```

However, this shows a sort of "slide down" animation. Is there a way that I can disable this animation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

try clearing the `RecyclerView` item animator

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

you can re-enable your animation after if needed.

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Comment: What about ViewPager2?

Answer (score 8):

You can also do it with Data Binding in your xml layout file like this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemAnimator="@{null}" />
```

This is possible simply because RecyclerView has a public function called `setItemAnimator`!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ListAdapter and Matthew's solution did not work for me, when I re-enable animation it active animation back. I use this if anybody else needed (Kotlin):

```
recyclerView.itemAnimator = null
adapter.submitList(items.toList()){
    recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
}
```

Comment: SubmitList is asynchronous. You can pass function argument as last parameter and it'll be triggered when list is submitted:
adapter.submitList(items.toList()) {
    recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
}

Comment: Thanks @BochenChleba, it's a significantly better solution, I will edit the answer